# How to get rid of the command line bar?

Tags: statusline, plugin-airline

I am using [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) and it's really nice.

[image: vim statusbar screenshot]

However, I get that second status bar below it which I want to hide.

I have tried `set noshowmode` in my `.vimrc`, but that only seemed to hide the default mode indicator.

Obviously the filename there is redundant (airline covers it) and the lines and char count aren't so useful to me.

Also, if I hide it, will it come back if I use `echoe "hello"` in my `.vimrc`?

[My `.vimrc`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexanderdickson/dotfiles/896344cabc02f29da7c2cb6979c9e97c4fad575b/vimrc)

Comment: Hi, does this provide help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8096378/2558252 ?

Comment: @Nobe4 Looks like from that link it may not be possible.

Comment: not possible. One is called a statusline, the other is the commandline. It is not possible to hide the commandline (and it wouldn't make sense anyhow).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's impossible to hide the command-line.

-- EDIT --

You can prevent Vim from echoing `"filename" XXXL, XXXC` when editing a file by prepending `silent` to `e`:

```
:silent e foo
```

Comment: Does any help article relate to this ?

Comment: @Nobe4, not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 11):

I finally found a way to get rid of the command, mode as well as file name in the command line bar!

at the **bottom** of your `.vimrc`:

```
set noshowmode  " to get rid of thing like --INSERT--
set noshowcmd  " to get rid of display of last command
set shortmess+=F  " to get rid of the file name displayed in the command line bar
```

notice that this piece of code should be at the **bottom** of your `.vimrc` or it may not works.

Comment: If you have to put these configs at the bottom of your vimrc it is because something else overrides them in your vimrc. It might be a plugin or something else, to check what it is you can use `:verbose set showmode?`.

Answer (score 6):

In [Vim 9.0.0114](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/f39cfb72629f3e7fefaf578a3faa2619cd0654f8)–9.0.0339 and [Neovim 0.8 (prerelease)](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases), `set cmdheight=0` hides the command line. Zero cmdheight was removed in [Vim 9.0.0340](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/a2a8973e51a0052bb52e43a2b22e7ecdecc32003).

Comment: This change got reverted in Vim, at least for now, because there were too many broken edge-cases and it wasn't deemed to be worth the maintenance effort. See: https://groups.google.com/g/vim_dev/c/FE1lWd-m3zU

Answer (score 2):

You hide the redundant line by setting `laststatus` to 1. Then airline goes away unless you have a split. You might be able to make airline set the `rulerformat` or set it to something else you like (and you probably need to `set ruler` as well).

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about the status line.  (airline)

Comment: The OP wants to get rid of the redundant line. Removing the status line is easy, removing the command line is likely not possible (nor particularly useful unless you never leave insert mode).

Comment: What about hiding it unless you're in command or ex mode? I'd like to hide it while in normal, visual, and insert, for example. Alternatively, maybe hide it as long as it's empty, then manually remove elements made redundant by airline?

Comment: I suppose I don't see why Airline is necessary here; if your goal is to get rid of redundant data then certainly it shouldn't matter which of the data gets hidden? :)