# How to show ruler always in the last line instead of statusline?

Tags: statusline, cmdline, ruler

From `h:ruler`:

> If a window has a status line, the ruler is shown there. Otherwise, it is shown in the last line of the screen.

How to instead show it only in the last line for the currently active window and hide it from the status line.

I currently suspect it it to be a hard limitation similar to the [inability to remove command line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6730/how-to-get-rid-of-the-command-line-bar?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe what you're asking is possible. You can remove the ruler from the statusline, however you cannot have it only appear on the bottom of the screen and be accurate to each window.

Comment: I want it to be accurate only to the focused window.